# Is there a batch version of Tweepy's 'destroy_friendship()' function?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

It appears that Tweepy's destroy_friendship() function, which unfollows a Twitter user, can only unfollow one user at a time - this presumably means that to unfollow many users, you have to make many API calls, and this counts against your rate limit.

Is there a batch version of the destroy_friendship() call, which would let you unfollow a list of Twitter users in one go, or some way to implement a functionality that could produce a comparable effect, without making numerous API call calls which count against your rate limit?

Answer (score 3):

Twitter's API does not have a call to destroy more than one friendship at a time. See the doc [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/destroy). However, you don't have to wait for `destroy_friendship()` to finish before calling it again. It will be faster if you spawn a thread each time you call `destroy_friendship()`.